# How do I get the username in Java (ie, who -m in Java) (or Jython 2.1)

Tags: java, jython

Here's the situation. I have a jython 2.1 script in a shared account that needs to know who is calling it. In bash, I can simply use $(who -m) and it will give me the correct username.

By "shared account", I mean I log in as myself, then $(sudo su - shared_account) to get to the shared account.

I haven't been able to find anything in java (or jython) that would give me a similar result. Even trying to call Runtime.getRuntime().exec("who -m") doesn't do anything. When I try to read the InputStream from the process returned by exec, the stream is empty.

Comment: When you say *username* are you referring to the login username as reported by the operating system?

Comment: Sort of. If I log in as amertune, then 'sudo su - shared_account', I want to get the username amertune (who -m does this), not the username shared_account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with an option, even though I don't really love it:

Add this flag to the java call:

```
-Duser.name="$(who -m | awk '{print $1}')"
```

And then access the user name with:

```
System.getProperty('user.name')
```

Comment: @amertune, pretty neat. Please note that I updated my answer with an example for getRunTime().exec().

Comment: Good idea ... but please **use a different property name**.  Other code and other programmers expect the `"user.name"` property to contain the name of the process owner.

Answer (score 3):

To get the process owner do this:

```
System.getProperty("user.name");
```

The syntax of getRunTime().exec() is tricky.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"/path/to/who", "-m"});
```

Comment: Not sure (but definitely too lazy to check), but I think this returns the process' owner, and not stdin's owner (as `who -m` does)

Comment: Exactly. I'm trying to get the stdin owner name (the account I originally logged in to), not the process owner name (the account I switched to with sudo).

Comment: @Romain, you're right, according to docs, it's `User's account name`.

Comment: The problem with Runtime.exec is that it doesn't seem to know who owns stdin. There is no output from 'who -m' in java.

Comment: @amertune, did you pass in the path and arguments separately for getRuntime().exec()?

Comment: From java.sun.com:

public Process exec(String command)
              throws IOException
Executes the specified string command in a separate process.
The command argument is parsed into tokens and then executed as    a command in a separate process. The token parsing is done by a StringTokenizer created by the call:

 new StringTokenizer(command)

If you pass the entire command with flags, then it will be tokenized. Essentially, exec("/path/to/who -m") works the same as exec(new String[] {"/path/to/who", "-m"})

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this.

```
System.out.println( System.getProperties().getProperty("user.name"));
```